# MongoDB prevent $inc from overflowing or underflowing field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

In my Meteor app, I have a method to adjust the quantity of certain elements from the client, and use `$inc` to keep things synchronized.

```
'item.update.qty'(id, qty) {
  // SECURITY validation here

  const modifier = {
    $inc: { qty }
  };

  Items.update(id, modifier);
}
```

And while I do validate that the quantity cannot set the given item in the negative, or beyond a certain limit, the server method does not restrict anyone from calling the method directly with invalid values. And since the method only relies on the item `id` and the `qty` to adjust, I lose the information of the current value.

Is it possible to clamp a field value, in MongoDB, to a given min/max boundary?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587866/mongodb-set-limit-to-inc

Comment: So, it is not possible to clamp a field value within MongoDB, and I must simpy reject the query and silently return?

Comment: Right, but you can still detect the case and flag the error if need be by seeing if a document was updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [aldeed:simple-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) you can [set min/max on numeric fields](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#minmax) and let simple-schema do the checking for you. For example:

```
ItemsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  qty: {
    type: Number,
    min: 0,
    max: 100
  }
});
```

Comment: No, this is a stateful answer. This kind of validation must be stateless and atomic; the validation must be at MongoDB's side. As I mentioned, I already have client and server side validation, but this cannot garantee that the model won't be concurrently modified and fall into an invalid state.